# Google Maps not displaying - Failed to decode tile

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I'm having a hard time trying to display a GMSMapView. I'm seeing a blank map as shown below.

[image]

I've seen plenty of answers indicating API Key was not valid or Maps iOS SDK not enable in Google console. But in my case, key works on sample projects. I even created a basic project and had no issues displaying the map.

This is what I see in the console:

```
2018-09-28 10:54:37.946703+0200 XXXXX[53857:723015] ((null)) was false: 

GMSStyledVectorMapTileService failed to decode tile [4,2,5], +[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a9af638
2018-09-28 10:54:38.063481+0200 XXXXX[53857:723015] +[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a9af638
2018-09-28 10:54:38.063666+0200 XXXXX[53857:723015] ((null)) was false: GMSStyledVectorMapTileService failed to decode tile [3,1,3], +[GMSx_GMPCClientVectorTileExtensionsRoot indoorBuildingMetadata]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a9af638
```

Please help, I'm dying here

Comment: Check if your `bundle ID` is the same with the entered under the API key in your Google API Console... or .. if  not had inverted the lat/long by mistake in Camera location...

Comment: There are no restrictions whatsoever for the moment with the key I generated. And, for lat and long, I just copied a sample code from the _Get Started_ section of Google tutorials, which works great on sample project, yet not on actual project I'm working on.

Comment: and what about the `bundle ID` ? Is the same?

Comment: I did not restrict the API key to any bundle ID so far. So there's no bundle ID on the Google console side. I did at first, with the same one as my target, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it's was kind of specific to my project. Google maps pod was shared among several target of my workspace project. It looks like the key wasn't shared among targets. Now maps pod is only used on main target and it's working fine.

Comment: Hey, can you please help me how you are able to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is either linkage problem or the Google Maps resources bundle is misplaced.

- Make sure you are linking the 3 GoogleMaps frameworks correctly and only once. In our case, the problem was only reproducible in release mode and the reason was that we were linking `GoogleMapsUtils` with GoogleMaps frameworks AND linking the app again with GoogleMaps frameworks.
- Also we had moved the `GoogleMaps.bundle` out of the framework and into our own framework, which was also probably a mistake.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's what we did, we only use it in our main kit. It was tricky to find the origin of the problem though ^^

Answer (score 0):

I handled it by integrating google maps manually. I still didn't find a fix by using cocoapods.